# Unrecognized selector sent to instance // swift 3

Tags: swift, decoding

I'm trying to get data back from UserDefaults.
I can store my code in it, but can't get it back.

This is my CustomAnnotation class

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, NSCoding, MKAnnotation {

    var tree:Tree!
    var title:String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees


    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, title:String, tree:Tree) {
        self.tree = tree
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        self.longitude = coordinate.longitude
    }

    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        self.tree = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "tree") as! Tree
        self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String
        self.coordinate = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "coordinate") as? CLLocationCoordinate2D)!
        self.latitude = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "latitude") as? CLLocationDegrees)!
        self.longitude = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "longitude") as? CLLocationDegrees)!
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(tree, forKey: "tree")
        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encode(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        aCoder.encode(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        aCoder.encode(coordinate,forKey:"coordinate")
    }
}
```

And i'm getting it back like this

```
let decoded = defaults.object(forKey: "savedAnnotations") as! Data
let decodedAnnotations = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [CustomAnnotation]
```

Error:

```
2017-04-22 19:01:08.751710+0200 Sam_Goeman_Multec_werkstuk2v2[3665:981692] -[Tree initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17447ee00
2017-04-22 19:01:08.751923+0200 Sam_Goeman_Multec_werkstuk2v2[3665:981692] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tree initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17447ee00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182ed2fd8 0x181934538 0x182ed9ef4 0x182ed6f4c 0x182dd2d2c 0x183922420 0x183921b58 0x10001c120 0x10001cd04 0x183922420 0x183928f00 0x1838be83c 0x183922420 0x183921b58 0x183920d84 0x100014de8 0x100011360 0x100011588 0x189001f9c 0x1890ba0c4 0x1890b9f9c 0x1890b92cc 0x1890b8d00 0x1890b88b4 0x1890b8818 0x188fff158 0x1861ef274 0x1861e3de8 0x1861e3ca8 0x18615f360 0x1861863c0 0x186186e8c 0x182e809a0 0x182e7e628 0x182daedb4 0x18906c45c 0x189067130 0x10001a51c 0x181dbd59c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

After some research here, I couldn't find the answer. I think it's about something optional but i'm not sure.

Comment: Read the error. It's about your `Tree` class. It also need to conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: Unrelated but do not store data like this into `UserDefaults`. Write the data to a file.

Comment: Does `Tree` conform to `NSCoding`?

Comment: I'm a beginner so I don't know how I can make my class conform to NSCoding. That class is made by CoreDate itself, is there any possible way to access that class and make it conform?

Comment: Also, you will probably need `decodeDouble` for `latitude` and `longitude` or  use `as NSNumber` when encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance` means that you have called a method on an object which does not implement that method. To fix your error, you should check the following –

The Tree class **must** conform to the NSCoding Protocol. It should look something like `class Tree: NSObject, NSCoding`. The Tree class also needs to implement `required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)`

Next, you cannot archive `CLLocationCoordinate2D` because it's not NSCoding compliant. You can encode / decode the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values like –

```
encode(coordinate.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
encode(coordinate.longitude, forKey: "longitude")


decodeDouble(forKey: "latitude")
decodeDouble(forKey: "longitude")
self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

You should then delete `latitude`, `longitude` variables because they are unnecessary.

Backing up for a minute, why are you storing a core data object in user defaults? Maybe understanding that will help me solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm trying to store a core data object in user defaults because of the following reason.

I'm making an app who makes a request and gets trees back. Those trees have a location (in string format). Then I use a geocoder to convert that string address to a coordinate, and then place an annotation. But that takes a while. So I want to store all those annotations in userdefaults so the app doesn't always need to geocode.
Hope this clear some things out